# Calculate centerPoint using transformation point

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations

I need help with a formula to calculate the centerpoint of an object taking into account variable width, and variable anchor/transform origin.

I have a rectangle with position & anchor at `(0,0)` and variable width. Default behavior when I change the width, is that the shape remains positioned at the origin and expands outwards on both sides. **Example: A**

If I were to define an anchor at `(-2, 0)`, `(-3, 0)`, or even outside the bounds at `(-4, 0)` and changed the width, I'd like to be able to calculate the centerpoint of the shape with regard to the anchor and width bearing in mind that any width changes are always applied symmetrically around the center of the shape. **Examples: B, C, D**

the black **+** is the defined transform anchor.

[image: Example Transforms with varying anchors.]

I can figure out C's equation, but my brain is refusing to figure out one that would work for B, C, and D...

c's center = anchor + (anchor + size) / 2;

Comment: Example B seems to be wrong. Do you mean "stretching plane" about the anchor point? Like a surface of an infinite balloon?

Comment: You're correct, B's blue rectangle should be positioned more to the right. The functionality is the same as when you move the transform origin in photoshop before resizing. Essentially scaling around an arbitrary point, similarly to rotating around a point.

Comment: When you pick an anchor the stretching just changes the position of each point in reference to this point by multiplying the x value by the stretching factor. You could implement it also in 2D.